# WPF Datagrid records is displaying couple of times

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I designed the below `DataGrid` and mapped with three colums. I had taken the records through `Linq` and assigned with this `Grid`. But this grid was displaying the records couple of times. 
I don't know what is the behaviour? How to sort it out this issue?

```
<DataGrid Name="workgrid" ItemsSource="{Binding it}" Margin="12,152,0,148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="517">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PersonName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Place}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


var objResult = from c in objEntities.PersonAccounts
        select new { c.PersonName, c.Amount, c.Place };

workgrid.ItemsSource = objResult;
```

Anu help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Do you mean records are being duplicated?

Comment: May be your `AutogenerateColumns` property is `true` by default in `DataGrid` object? If the duplicate in columns and not in rows..

Comment: Yes. It has been duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoGenerateColumns to false :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="workgrid" ItemsSource="{Binding it}" Margin="12,152,0,148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="517">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PersonName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Place}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also, you don't need to set ItemsSource explicitely and by binding. Just use one.